# Why is setTimeout preventing recursive $http.get call

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have looked both here on SO and Googled it but I am struggling to find any solution to this.

I have the below function and when I don't use the `setTimeout()` function and just call my polling function it works as expected. But when I try to wrap my polling function inside a `setTimeout()` it works once and then doesn't get called again unless the page is refreshed, I have already included a timestamp in the GET request to prevent using a cached response so I don't think this is the issue. I have also checked and this behaviour happens in IE9, Firefox and Chrome.

```
$scope.progressPolling = function () {
    var time = new Date().toString();
    console.log("time :" + time);

    $http.get('pollprogress?time=' + time + '&id=' + $scope.jobID)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            var percent = data.percentage;
            if (parseInt($scope.progress) < 100) {
                if (percent <= 100) {
                    $scope.progress = percent;
                }
                setTimeout(function() {
                    if (parseInt($scope.progress) < 100) {
                        temp = parseInt($scope.progress) + 1;
                        $scope.progressPolling();
                    };
                }, 5000);
            }
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("Error updating Progress: " + data);
        });
}
```

Comment: Try using `$timeout()` instead of `setTimeout()`

Comment: @CodeHater That solved it thanks, Do you know what causes this Issue or what $timeout does differently that it doesn't occur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change it to `$timeout`

```
$scope.progressPolling = function () {
var time = new Date().toString();
console.log("time :" + time);

var stop;

$http.get('pollprogress?time=' + time + '&id=' + $scope.jobID)
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        var percent = data.percentage;
        if (parseInt($scope.progress) < 100) {
            if (percent <= 100) {
                $scope.progress = percent;
            }
           stop = $timeout(function() {
                if (parseInt($scope.progress) < 100) {
                    temp = parseInt($scope.progress) + 1;
                    $scope.progressPolling();
                }
                   else{
                     $timeout.cancel(stop);
                   }
            }, 5000);
        }
    })
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("Error updating Progress: " + data);
    });
}
```

As a side note, create factory:

```
 myModule.factory('delay', ['$q', '$timeout', function ($q, $timeout) {
 return {
    start: function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $timeout(deferred.resolve, 5000);
        return deferred.promise;
      }
   };
 }]);
```

After you can call it like:

```
$q.all([delay.start(), /*your method */]);`
```

Comment: thanks that solves my problem, could you explain what causes the issue though and what `$timeout` does to solve it so that I am not just blindly using it

Comment: well, `setTimeout` is jQuery and you need `$apply()` to bind with angular. However `$timeout` is angular method and my opinion to prevent above mentioned problems use  angular only :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason `setTimeout` appears to not work is because the callback function is executing outside of a digest cycle, so the bindings aren't updated. The `$timeout` service wraps the call with `$scope.$apply(...)` so the UI is updated.  You could do it yourself in the `setTimeout` callback.